# Bad php file opened with PHP server in Visual Studio Code (old project)

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I'm on macOS.
I am using Visual Studio Code with PHP Server and Live Server Web Extension.
I used it for a project, everything works fine.

I opened a second project in a different directory.
I launch Go Live and when I right click "open file in browser", the first project opens.
Unable to see the second project in Chrome.
The server always points to the wrong project

An idea please ?

I uninstalled PHP Server but it doesn't work.
I cleared the VSC cache but it doesn't work.
I have restarted VSC several times but it does not work.

If I exit Visual Studio Code completely, then the http://localhost:3000/ link still works perfectly.
I was able by changing all the ports, to run another project: http://localhost:8000/
Both projects are accessible (locally) even if VSC is closed.
Where are the urls stored with the links to the files please?
How to point http://localhost:3000/ to another file?

I thought about doing a DNS flush but that didn't work.
I'm on MacOS

Comment: What is a PHP Server, no such animal I am afraid

Comment: Search "php server" in Visual Studio Code:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=brapifra.phpserver

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: [phpserver.relativePath](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=brapifra.phpserver#:~:text=phpserver.relativePath.)  ??  ("Path relative to project. This is useful when you want to serve a different folder than the one from current workspace.")

Comment: Hi! This community is only about programming related questions. Yes we might have some experience with web servers as well. But maybe you should ask on one of the other StackExchange sites like [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) or maybe [webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
This is not related to the web server but to the operation of Visual Studio Code, with the Php Server module, locally. other people have addressed the problem here, and had an answer for Windows. I'm on Mac.